# Input variable box is not appearing and asking for input value and loop is not working

Tags: python, loops, input, try-catch, except

write a program that repeatedly read numbers until the user enters "done". Once "done" is entered, print out the total, count, and average numbers. if the user enters anything other than number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

Enter a number: 4 Enter a number: 5 Enter a number: bad data Invalid input Enter a number: 7 Enter a number: done 
""" """Approach1 """

```
Number = input(Enter a number: )
count = 0
total = 0
average = 0
try:
    number = float(Number)
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input')
    quit()
while True:                               # Stays in loop until break
    number = input('Enter a number: ')
    if number == 'done':
        break                             # Exits the while loop

    number = check_for_float(input_number)
for a number in Number:
    count = count + 1
    total = total + 1
    average = number / count
    print("Total:", total , "Count:", count, "Average: ", average)
```

After running this program, I was expecting an input box to pop and ask for input value which is not happening. Please advise.

Comment: Is `Number = input(Enter a number: )` as its written in your program? `input` needs a string as a parameter; you've forgotten to put quotes around this text.

Comment: This is code that you can either execute from within the Python shell or from the command line as a script stored in a .py file. In both cases, you will receive a text prompt with the message passed to the `input()` function. No GUI involved.